# Function to split string and reverse it in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, string, split

I have a column as "**Name**" in two different tables and i want to split the name into two different columns as "**FirsrName**" and "**LastName**". What I'm doing is to create a function and get the values as First and Last.

**Issue:** 
Case 1 - The main issue is in first table, name resides as "Sahil Sharma" so i have to split the name on the basis of space.
Case 2 - In second table, the name is like "Sharma;Sahil" so I need to split the function on the basis of ; and also reverse it as the output of the function be like: 
FirstName - Sahil
LastName - Sharma

I'm a bit begineer in CHARINDEX and SUBSTRINGS, although after reading the MSDN, I have tried this code:

`---Get First Name`

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFirstName](@fullname varchar(30))
    RETURNS varchar(20)
    AS 
    BEGIN

DECLARE @name nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @result [nvarchar](30)
SET @name = @fullname

--To Check for names for CRMS
IF(CHARINDEX(';', @name) > 0)
SET @result = SUBSTRING(@name, 0, CHARINDEX(';', @name))

---To Check names for eGlobal
ELSE
SET @result = SUBSTRING(@name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @name))
RETURN @result

END
GO
```

---Get Last Name

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLastName](@fullname varchar(30))
    RETURNS varchar(20)
    AS 
    BEGIN

DECLARE @name nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @result [nvarchar](30)
SET @name = @fullname

--To Check for names for CRMS
IF(CHARINDEX(';', @name) > 0)
SET @result = SUBSTRING(@name, CHARINDEX(';', @name) + 1, LEN(@name) - CHARINDEX(';', @name));

---To Check names for eGlobal
ELSE
SET @result = SUBSTRING(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name) + 1, LEN(@name) - CHARINDEX(' ', @name));

RETURN @result
END
GO
```

This code is not working as I think I'm missing something. My understanding is CHARINDEX searches an character from the string and SUBSTRING can retrieve the part of the string for me.

What I'm doing in the code is searching blank space (' ') using CHARINDEX and then getting it using SUBSTRING but its not working. Is this the right approach or can I refactor it more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the last name you need to start from where the space is and take length of @name minus where the space is:

```
select SUBSTRING(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name) + 1, LEN(@name) - CHARINDEX(' ', @name))
```

But you might need to handle first name differently if you have `first_name space mid_name space last_name`

2nd argument to SUBSTRING is the position where to start taking characters from and the last argument is the length.

Edit:

You can also use REVERSE to get the location of the last space:

```
CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@name), 0)
```

I'm also pretty positive giving a length for SUBSTRING which is longer than the length of the string, will return the full string so last name could also be calculated as:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@name), 0) - 1, 500)
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring Can't you start searching from the end to 'skip' the middle name but i guess it would need more calculation to see where the first-from-the-end space is relative to the start-of-the-string.  (?)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I have updated the question and modified the code using the suggestion.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier See the edit for using the position of the last space in case of middle name.